# can php get value from url after hash with js href.split?

Tags: php, javascript, hash, get, split

I have some urls like `http://www.domainname.com/m1.php?#m2.php?more=apple&starting=1`

How to use PHP to get the value `$_GET['more']` & `$_GET['starting']`?

Is it possible use js `href.split` to get the value hehind hash `#`?

Updated question:

Add some code as below: I still get the `$_GET['fragment'] = m2.php?more=apple`, but lose the `&starting=1`, How do I do next?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var parts = location.href.split('#');
if(parts.length > 1)
{
    var params = parts[0].split('?');
    var mark = '?';
    if(params.length > 1)
    {
        mark = '&';
    }
    location.href = parts[0] + mark + 'fragment=' + parts[1];
}
</script>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['fragment']))
{
    echo $_GET['fragment'];
}
?>
```

Comment: JS would be the ONLY way to get the hash portion to send to the client, and then only by extracting it from the URL and inserting as a regular query parameter.

Comment: @Marc B, so if use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` get the current page's url. then use `parse_url` get the `fragment` part, then do something expolore 2 values... Is it possible?

Comment: request_uri doesnt' have fragment

Comment: @yes123, so how to get a current url with fragment?

Comment: @yes123: Wah, you are right. [RFC 2396](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#section-4) cleary states, that fragments are client-side only. Slipped out of my brain. Should go to bed. Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you simply can't see the fragment requested.

You can see it only with javascript

Comment: so do u have any idea, how to get value from js and pass to php?

Comment: you are asking too much stuff within one question. With js you can take that with `window.location.hash` once you have this string with jQuery you can make a simple ajax call (open another question if you don't know how to make an ajax call)

Comment: ok, still back to this question as my title descript, I do not ask more out of this topic. I update my question, add some code. Could u help me solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use PHP's built in function `parse_url` http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

If you look at the return values, you can get the query params as a hash and the value after the `#` is the `fragment`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to use the hash fragment in php.

Needs page reload but it works.
You can set this script tag before any other js tag so the reload is not delayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.hash.length > 0){
    var hash = location.hash.replace('#','');
    location.href = hash;
    //or
    //location.href = 'index.php?param1=1&hash'+hash;
    //or
    //location.href = '<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'&hash='?>'+hash;
}
</script>
```